# Incorporating several basic ideas in C++ issue

Tags: c++

Code;

```
# include <iostream>
# include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    int var1 = 1;
    int var2 = 1;
    bool while1 = true;
    int x = 0;

    while (x < 999) {
        x = x+var1;
        x = x+var2;
        cout << x << " Is the current value of x, how much would you like to add to it?\n";
        Sleep(1000);
        while (while1) {
            int var3;
            cin>> var3;
            if (var3 > 100) {
                cout << "Too large, between 10 and 100\n";
                while1 = true;
            } 
            else if (var3 < 10) {
                cout << "Too small, between 10 and 100\n";
                while1 = true;
            }
            else{
                cout << "Adding " << var3 << " to " << x << "\n";
                x = x + var3;
                cout << "x is now " << x << "\n";
                while1 = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is after it loops back up the first time it completely skips over the second while statement and proceeds to continue adding just var1 and var2 to x.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 4):

You never reset the variable to `true`. Put this somewhere in the outer loop, like right before the `while (while1) {` line:

```
while1 = true;
```

As it is, it stays false from when you set it in the `else` part. Alternatively, make it an infinite loop (`for (;;)` or `while (true)`) and just use `break;` instead of `while1 = false;`, then completely erase mention of `while1` in the other two.

Also, your outer loop could be replace with a `for` loop:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 999;)
```

This could even remove the need for the two `x = x + var1; x = x + var2;` statements as well. I'll keep it in terms of `var1` and `var2`:

```
for (int x = -var1 - var2; x < 999; x += var1 + var2)
```

`var1` and `var2` also never change, so if there's some actual meaning to them, I suggest making them `const` and renaming them to something that conveys that meaning. Else, just say `x = x + 2`, or shorter, `x += 2;`.

Finally, if you use C++11, you can get rid of the `<windows.h>` dependency by using the standard sleep function instead:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
...
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
```

Comment: Hey, but can you explain to me why I have to reset the variable to 'true`? Isn't it already defined as true when I said `bool while1 = true;`?

Comment: @Spaceman, You declare it once outside of the outer loop. Only the code in the loop is repeated, so instead of making a new variable that's once again true, it never touches it. For comparison, imagine how bad it would be if `x` was recreated and set to 0 every loop iteration.

Comment: Chris, you're amazing. Thanks for taking the time to help a novice like me.

Comment: @Spaceman, No problem. As this is your first question, I do recommend you read the [faq], particularly [this section](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) and keep it in mind when participating on the site.

Comment: If you add the reset of while1 to true as Chris states, then the extra assignments inside the comparison if-else blocks don't need to be there.  while1 will stay true until you change it in the case where 10 < var3 < 100.

Comment: @user973572, I was kind of thinking that while writing my answer, but I never expressed clearly that it could even be done without using the `break;` suggestion. Thank you for clarifying.